# Excel - Total Count of multiple reasons

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, data-analysis

Ideally, I am looking for a solution where I can see the total number of reasons why the device failed, which is currently recorded in a dropdown list on excel (with option for multiple entries). When using a pivot table I'm only able to see the all the different combinations rather than sole counts of A,B,C etc.... Ideally looking to create options that give this but at each stage of failure (all 5) too.

Currently, the data looks like this:

```
| Reference Number | Stage of Faliure | Reason For Failure |
| --------         | --------------   | ------------------ |
| First            | 1                | A, B               |
| Second           | 2                | A, C               |
```

Any ideas appreciated & hope this is enough context to explain the issue.

Ideal goal
Currently, the data looks like this:

```
| Reason for Failure | Total Count | Stage 1 Count | Stage 2 Count |
| --------           | ----------- | ------------  | --------------|
| A                  | 2           | 1             | 1             |
| B                  | 1           | 1             | 0             |
```

Answer (score 1):

The key here is that `COUNTIF()` and `COUNTIFS()` can accept wildcards in a string comparison.

If your data looks like this:

[image: Data]

Then your formulas can look like this:

[image: Formulas]

Total Count: `=COUNTIFS(C$2:C$20,"*"&E2&"*")`

Stage 1 Count: `=COUNTIFS(B$2:B$20,1,C$2:C$20,"*"&E2&"*")`

Stage 2 Count: `=COUNTIFS(B$2:B$20,2,C$2:C$20,"*"&E2&"*")`

Just be careful when your settings up the ranges you reference as absolute (`$`) or relative (no `$`) so that it'll work the way you want when you copy/paste down.

Answer (score 0):

As the variant, it can be done transformation of the initial table

> ```
> Reference Number | Stage of Faliure | Reason For Failure |
> | --------         | --------------   | ------------------ |
> | First            | 1                | A, B               |
> | Second           | 2                | A, C               |
> ```

Particulary, to split the lines with several "Reason For Failure" entries for several separate lines with one of the value, like this

> ```
>   Reference Number | Stage of Faliure | Reason For Failure |
> | --------         | --------------   | ------------------ |
> | First            | 1                | A               |
> | Second           | 2                | C               | 
> | First            | 1                | A               |
> | Second           | 2                | A               |
> | First            | 1                | B               |
> | Second           | 2                | C               |
> ```

Then - to made filtering and/or groupping by columns using standard Excel table operations

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).